# Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, browser-history, connected-react-router

[image]

I am using these versions

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
"connected-react-router": "^6.8.0"
"history": "4.10.1"
```

export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({
basename: '/clearance-authorization'
})

i am getting this Error Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

reducers.js

```
export default (history) => {
const appReducer = (asyncReducer) => {
  return combineReducers({
    notifications,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...asyncReducer
  })
}
const rootReducer = (state, action) => appReducer(state, action)
return rootReducer
}
```

store.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: '/clearance'
})
const middleware = [routerMiddleware(history), sagaMiddleware, notifications]

const configureStore = (initialState) => {
  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(history),
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      getReduxDevTools(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    )
  )
  store.asyncReducers = {}
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run
  store.close = () => store.dispatch(END)
  return store
    }

export default configureStore
```

App.js

```
import configureStore, { history } from './redux/store'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

  <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Frame handleScrolling={false}>
         </Frame>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
```

Comment: What is `createReducer` that is used in the `createStore` function?

Comment: import createReducer from './reducers' =>  createReducer is the appReducer

Comment: I see. Then it appears `appReducer` is passed a history object but renames it `asyncReducer` and something else is passed to `connectRouter`.

Comment: my bad, some code missed now you can see history is being passed

Comment: That create reducer function doesn't seem quite correct. What is `asyncReducer`? It looks like it's the `state` object from `const rootReducer = (state, action) => appReducer(state, action)`.

Comment: hey thank you Drew , i got it i have removed rootReducer and only returned the combineReducers

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

From your description and error it seems you've not added the connected router to your root reducer.

## Solution

Import `connectRouter` function and create the root reducer with a `router` key and pass the `history` object. Redux doesn't have a matching reducer, or specifically the `connected-react-router` selectors are attempting to select from non-existent state.

[Example from docs](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router#usage):

> In your root reducer file,
>
> - Create a function that takes `history` as an argument and returns a root reducer.
> - Add `router` reducer into root reducer by passing `history` to `connectRouter`.
> - **Note: The key MUST be `router`.**
>
>   ```
>   // reducers.js
>   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
>   import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
>   ... // res of your reducers
>
>   const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
>     router: connectRouter(history),
>     ... // rest of your reducers
>   });
>
>   export default createRootReducer;
>   ```

...

Import your history object and custom `createRootReducer` for use when creating your Redux store. Follow the rest of the `connected-react-router` docs for specifics.

Example:

```
import { browserHistory } from '../path/to/history';
import createRootReducer from './reducers';

...

createRootReducer(browserHistory);
```

Comment: i am passing the history to createRootReduce, and also added the  **router: connectRouter(history)** still its same

Comment: @C09-G Please share all the relevant code you're working with, it's hard to debug code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: edited the post with code please have a look @drew-reese

Answer (score 0):

changed the code in reducers
reducers.js

```
export default (history) => {
  return combineReducers({
    notifications,
    referenceData,
    clearance,
    lotNotes,
    siteTour,
    buyerNotes,
    router: connectRouter(history)
  })
}
```